# gcovr with Cobertura XML output gives absolute path of production files

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage, cobertura, gcovr

I have managed to show code coverage data with Cobertura XML in Jenkins.
Its works well, but I wants to see the source code in Jenkins, too.
I accidentally saw, that Jenkins is referring for the source files at my windows harddrive, but the files are on a Jenkins server (different PC). This happens maybe, because in Cobertura output XML, the "filename" refers to an absolute path and not relative from directory. The XML attribute looks like `filename="C:/Users/PathToMySources"`.

How I can change filenames in Cobertura XML to be relative?

gcovr.exe is invoked like this:

```
gcovr.exe --filter ../MySources/ --branches --html-details Test.html --cobertura Test.xml
```

My Project look like this:

```
MyProject
|
|---Library A (has subfolders)
|
|---Library B (has subfolders)
|
|---TestFolder for Library A and B (has subfolders)
```

This Layout is like this because Library A, B and Testfolders are externals in svn for sharing the library to everyone in the company.
With gcovr I refered for example to Library B. In Library B,  I have subfolders. Some Subfolders contains only headers because of template classes in C++.
Now I saw another issue.
With --filter, the header only classes are included in coverage output, with --root they are not included!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, you can fix things by changing `--filter` to `--root`.

Gcovr has a concept of a “root” directory which defaults to the current working directory. The root is used for various purposes like serving as a default filter, but also for deciding how file names are presented in reports.

- If a file path is within the root directory, a path relative from the root directory is shown.
- Otherwise, an absolute path is shown

It is unusual to ever see an absolute path in a gcovr report, unless you're trying to include coverage for a library outside of your project directory, or if you're using the `--html-absolute-paths` option.

Comment: @user19471767 Could you edit the information about your project layout into the question?

Comment: Well with --root, I have no coverage data. I have no input in html files, it is empty.
Ok I solved that problem now, but I opened a new problem. Now I have no coverage data for my header only template classes :(

Comment: @user19471767 This might need a more complicated invocation where the root covers both your libraries and your current working directory, and you use a filter to narrow down the report. For example `gcovr --root ../ --filter ../LibraryB OTHER_OPTIONS`.

Comment: This made the trick. Thank you!! Now, I can see the source code in Jenkins!